# What is the goal of subnetting?

Tags: router

Im trying to understand what subnetting is and how it works, but im pretty confused.

So, from my understanding subnetting is when you take a public ip address assigned to a network, and you can then take this address and use the Network ID portion to create different sub networks, and then use the Host ID portion to identify different hosts on that subnetwork. My question is, how that hell dose that work when your network is assigned a single public IP?? If for example my router's assigned public IP address is 30.52.165.0, could i have a subnet with an IP of 30.52.166.0, and then have a device on that subnet with an IP of 30.52.165.0? And if thats true, wouldnt that pollute the public IP address space? And what would the purpose of private IP addresses be then?

Sorry, im not sure how to even ask this question. I just want to know what subnetting does, and if im looking at this completley wrong.

Comment: P.S, I also know NAT exists, and basically what it dose is it temporarily substitutes the source address of an IP packet from a host on the network, for its one public address so that IP address space is saved. Why the hell would we need subnetting then? Do they solve different issues?

Comment: Every IPv4 network is a subnet of `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: the goal is to assign addresses hierarchically. We had a long discussion on how this is supposed to work in [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76629/what-happens-to-the-unused-ip-addresses-in-the-subnet-that-falls-in-between-two/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you take *any* single private or public network and you create multiple networks from it (to provide addresses for different locations, security zones, better scaling, ...).

> how [..] does that work when your network is assigned a single public IP?

It doesn't. You need a network to start with.

> If for example my router's assigned public IP address is 30.52.165.0, could i have a subnet with an IP of 30.52.166.0 ...

The IP address your router uses to talk to its uplink might not be related to what's routed over it *at all*.

> And what would the purpose of private IP addresses be then?

Private addresses are agreed upon to *not be used on the Internet*. You can use them freely as you wish without creating any ambiguity for your network. However, you must not use them on any outside interface - you need to translate or obscure them in any way you see fit (NAPT, proxy, ...).

Of course, you can use a private network like 10.0.0.0/8, subnet that across dozens or even hundreds of locations around the world, and hide all that behind a single public IP address.

Comment: "You need a network to start with", i think "address range" is a better term for this

Comment: "Of course, you can use a private network like 10.0.0.0/8, subnet that across dozens or even hundreds of locations around the world, and hide all that behind a single public IP address." - In response to this statement, could you explain how that would work?

Comment: would 10.0.0.0 be the public ip, and 10.0.1.0 or 10.0.25.43  or anything the like could be subnets of it?? And if so, would 10.0.0.1 to 10.255.255.255 all potencially be subnets or hosts of that network? And if so, wouldnt that be a huge waste of public IP values?

Comment: @Effie Well, the address range needs to have a common prefix, so it's actually a network, seen from afar. Of course, it all depends on nomenclature.

Comment: @KeylimePi No, 10.0.0.0/8 is private as per RFC 1918. You could have 10.0.0.0/16 for one location, 10.1.0.0/16 for the next, 10.2.0.0/16, 10.3.0.0/16, and so on. Each location could subnet to /24 for the actual IP subnets. Connect them all together (via dark fiber, MPLS, VPN, laser, satellite links, whatever) and use a central NAPT gateway for Internet connectivity. Of course, it's more common to use a public *address pool* rather than a single address, but the latter is absolutely possible as well.

Comment: Ohh alright. So basically i could be given a public address of 154.3.25.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, and i could then use the network id portion to create a subnet like 154.3.26.0. And if i were to have a host on that subnet it could have an ip address of 154.3.26.1, for example. Im i understanding correctly? @Zac67

Comment: I think i can understand subnetting in a private network, but dosent subnetting a public ip address waste IP address space? Is that just how it is or am i understanding wrong?

Comment: I don't see the waste, unless it's done wastefully. An ISP needs to subnet their public address space for their own infrastructure and for address ranges provided to customers.

Comment: So basically, if needed, an organization with a large network can be provided an entire range of addresses, which they'll use to  subnet their network? Like if a company's network was assigned the address 164.32.4.3/24, how far would their potencial ip addresses range?

Comment: 164.32.4.3/24 is a single address from the 164.32.4.0/24 subnet, so it's not actually a range.

Comment: /24 means that 24 bits are fixed. the remainder 8 bits can be assigned, which gives at most 255 different values. Now, there is another issue. In every range except /31 range, the lowest and the highest values are reserved. So the actual number is smaller.

Comment: @Effie `0` is a value, too. ;-)

Comment: I just wrote on subnetting for work and you might find it useful... Any comments appreciated!

https://pcolladosoto.github.io/2021/12/16/ip-subnetting.html

Answer (score -1):

The goal of subnetting is to lower the distance data packets need to travel in the network. In doing so, devices can communicate more efficiently with smaller networks.

Subnetting reduces the heavy load on the same network and routes data more efficiently, not to mention it also boosts the network’s security and reduces IPv4 wastage.